# React Native screen display cut off at top and bottom, and app looks zoomed in

Tags: ios, react-native

Out of nowhere, the display on my app is cut off and there are two black bars at the top and bottom. It looks almost like watching a wide-screen film on a television set where the aspect ratio is adjusted.

Because the display has been resized, the display elements appear much larger and the app has a "zoomed in" look. I'm going through my commit history trying to see what happened, and I'm worried I accidentally made a change in Info.plist. I also thought maybe I had made a mistake with Dimensions or flex settings, but I've gone through my commit history and I haven't made any changes to them.

Is anybody aware of what might be causing this, or which settings in xCode/Info.plist control this?

I'll continue going through my commit history and I'll post a solution if I find one. Thanks.

[image: screen capture]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem.
The issue is due to missing Splash screen.
Create LaunchScreen.storyboard and than in your Project->Targets settings
[select "Launch Screen File"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDyoH.png)

Clean project and Rebuild.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out and report back on what happened and mark as the accepted answer if it works. Come to think of it, I was researching adding a splash screen, and I did click around on there in the Xcode browser. I probably broke something by accident...

Comment: That was exactly the issue. Appreciate the advice!

Comment: This works. It's strange for the entire afternoon after I configure the splash screen everything works fine and until I do yarn install this issue starts to show up.